# How can I run Java Flight Recorder in the Intellij Idea community development environment with OpenJDK 16

Tags: intellij-idea, java-16

I am interested to run **Java Flight Recorder** wiht **Intellij Idea Community**.

By path

```
  -> Run|Edit configuration
```

I have pointed the options:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename="D:\!_git\tmp\core-java-perf\file.jfr"
```

But I don't find the file -> **file.jfr**;

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to work with **Java Flight Recorder** from the **Intellij Idea community**?

Answer (score 1):

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures 
-XX:+FlightRecorder
```

It is deprecated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So this works with the **Community Edition**?